# Find Sheet Name with table on it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the sheet name that has a specific table name on it. For example:

```
Set sheetNM = ActiveWorkbook.Names("ratetable").RefersToRange.Parent.Name
```

Something like that, but would pull the name of the sheet, so I can activate that sheet in order to pull information from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use error trapping to find the sheet containing a table with a given name:

```
Function FindTableSheet(TableName As String) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Dim shName As String

    For Each ws In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set LO = ws.ListObjects(TableName)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            FindTableSheet = ws.Name
            Exit Function
        Else
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Next ws
    FindTableSheet = "Not Found"
End Function
```

To test it, I named one of my sheets "Data" and added a table called "ratetable" to that sheet. I didn't, however, create any table called "table tennis". I then ran:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print FindTableSheet("ratetable")
    Debug.Print FindTableSheet("table tennis")
End Sub
```

With the output:

```
Data
Not Found
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not something I recommend but as you are referencing the [ActiveWorkbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx), you can drop the `ActiveWorkbook` and retrieve it simply as,

```
dim pws as worksheet, sws as string
sws = range("ratetable").parent.name
set pws = range("ratetable").parent
debug.print sws & " - " & pws.name
```

While a structured table (aka [ListObject object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247(v=office.11).aspx)) is listed in the Formulas ► Name Manager, it does not have all of the properties of a defined name. Unfortunately, everything you can do with a name you cannot always do with a ListObject as a ListObject's parent is the Worksheet object, not the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

With the name of the table in A1, you can get the sheet name with this formula (directly in Excel, no VBA needed):

```
=MID(CELL("filename",INDIRECT(A1&"[#All]")),FIND("]",CELL("filename",INDIRECT(A1&"[#All]")))+1,999)
```

- `INDIRECT(A1&"[#All]")` returns the table itself.
- `CELL("filename",INDIRECT(...))` returns the file name including the sheet name of the table, in a format like "C:...[filename.xlsx]SheetName".
- `FIND("]", CELL(...))` returns the index of the closing bracket in the file name with the sheet name.
- `MID(CELL(...),FIND("]", CELL(...))+1,999)` extracts the sheet name from the file name, from after the closing bracket to the end.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is old, but for what it's worth, I think the OP was on the right track (looking for the parent name) with the initial code that you originally posted.  Calling the table's parent works for me:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableName").Parent.Name
```

Comment: You assume the table is located on the active sheet which is obviously not the case. OP is looking for the sheet.